# Gitbook Export to Github

Tags: github, gitbook

I created a GitBook and want to export it to GitHub. I went into the settings of the GitBook and clicked on Export to GitHub. Provided the URL to my GitBook repo, entered a valid name for my new GitHub repository and clicked on Begin Import. When I do so I get a message saying "Your old project requires credentials for read-only access", I enter my GitHub info but it doesn't work. I have to re-enter my login information over and over again. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why. Curiously, no password was set for my account.